# NSMutableOrderedSet to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsorderedset, nsmutableorderedset

```
array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[set allObjects]];
```

This worked with an `NSSet`, but how do I get it to work with an `NSMutableOrderedSet`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

there is a method on the NSOrderedSet class to get an array `[orderedSet array]`. you can then do `[array mutableCopy]` to get a mutable array.

or use `[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[set array]];` if you prefer.

do be aware of this, however:

> This return a proxy object for the receiving ordered set, which acts like an immutable array.
>   While you cannot mutate the ordered set through this proxy, mutations to the original ordered set will be reflected in the proxy and it will appear to change spontaneously, since a copy of the ordered set is not being made.

basically you **must** copy the array if you don't want this behavior.

Comment: I had tried [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[set array]]; before and it was giving me an -[__NSSetM array]: unrecognized selector error message.  Not sure why

Comment: that is because __NSSetM is an NSMutableSet, not an NSMutableOrderedSet. you may be confused thinking that NSMutableOrderedSet descends from NSSet, but it does not.Anyway this is the correct answer for getting an NSMutableArray from an NSMutableOrderedSet as asked. So which do you need an answer for, NSMutableSet or NSMutableOrderedSet?

Comment: Thanks.  Just realized I was allocating it as an NSMutableSet and not an NSMutableOrderedSet.